# Provide "add as favorite" option when hovering over tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

The look and feel, as well as overall usability of the SE-sites, is awesome--I enjoy reading over here.

I think that the process to add favorite tags can be more practical: when hovering over a tag (a small window pops-up anyway with a definition and a few options to follow, et.c.), an option to mark this tag as favorite (of course for logged-in users) would simplify things.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is already implemented: Clicking on the star on the top left of a tag pop-up *"toggle[s] this tag between favorite, ignored, and normal"*.

Comment: How "blind" can I be then... ? The site(s) is(are) truly beautiful.